# Multiple plots in R on a pdf with a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I think I need help with the loop. How would you do multiple plots on separate pdf pages with the data below:

pdf page 1:
Mazda RX4
2 panel plot for mpg vs cyl and mpg vs vs

pdf page 2:
Hornet 4 D
2 panel plot for mpg vs cyl and mpg vs vs

and the same for Valiant.

model       mpg cyl vs 
Mazda RX4   21.0 6 0 
Mazda RX4   21.0 6 0 
Mazda RX4   22.8 4 1 
Hornet 4 D  21.4 6 1 
Hornet 4 D  18.7 8 0 
Valiant     18.1 6 1 
Valiant     21.4 6 1 
Valiant     21.0 6 0 
Valiant     22.8 6 0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case is set up the plots I want on one page with `gridExtra`, save that as a PDF, and then concatenate all these PDFs with ghostscript.

In R:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

plot_one <- ggplot() + geom_...
plot_two <- ggplot() + geom_...

# Arrange the two plots one per row.
# grid.arrange'd plots can be nested, too!
two_rows <- grid.arrange(plot_one, plot_two, nrow = 2)

ggsave("dataset_1.pdf", two_rows)

# repeat for second, third, etc datasets so you end up with dataset_2.pdf etc
```

These are then concatenated to one PDF with multiple pages with ghostscript:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dNOPAUSE \
   -dQUIET \
   -dBATCH \
   -sOutputFile=multipage.pdf \
   dataset_1.pdf dataset_2.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Derived from an example elsewhere (https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_save_the_graphics_in_several_separate_pages_with_R)

```
# Create pdf
pdf(...)

# Create different plots
plot1(...)
plot2(...)
plot3(...)

dev.off()
```

Note: set the parameter `onefile=FALSE` in `pdf()`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I forgot to mention that though I provided it for 3 car models, there are actually almost a hundred of them so, I was thinking of putting it into a loop.